# Java: Writing Private key from Windows-my to file .pem

Tags: java, windows, certificate, keystore, pem

I'm trying to get a certificate and a private key from Windows-MY keystore and write them on files, but I have some problems that make think that Java doesn't allow to write the PrivateKey from windows keystore to a file:

```
try {
  KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
  ks.load(null, null) ;
  java.util.Enumeration en = ks.aliases() ;

while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
    String aliasKey = (String)en.nextElement() ;
    Certificate c = ks.getCertificate(aliasKey) ;       

    if (aliasKey.equals("myKey") ) {
          PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(aliasKey, "monPassword".toCharArray());
          Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(aliasKey);

          //write key on PEM file
          wr1 = new FileWriter(directory.getPath() + "\\" + "key.pem");
          PemWriter pWr = new PemWriter(wr1);

          pemWr = new PEMWriter(wr1);           
        try {
             pemWr.writeObject(key);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pemWr.flush();
        pemWr.close();

    }
}

 } catch (Exception ioe) {
System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
 }
```

I Have an exception writing the key on file:

```
org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemGenerationException: unknown object passed - can't encode.
```

What make me thing of some sort of security protection is that:

1. key != null and key.getAlgorithm() != null
2. key.getEncode() == null and key.getFormat() == null
3. if I read the key from a file and then write it in another one, the code works and none of the methods return null

How can I write the key on a file .pem?
thank you
Daniele